# How can i access a remote server whose certificate has expired

Tags: windows, windows-server

I have a server running on GCP. Unfortunately the certificate expired and therefore cannot RDP. I am looking for a work around, to get into the server to renew the certificate.

I have access to the cmd through the serial console port.

How can i access the server or can i renew certificate through cmd?
[RDP Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cesAQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The shown message is not related to the server's certificate. It specifically talks about the certificate used to *digitally sign the .rdp file* (the same form of signatures as is used for .exe programs). A signed .rdp file shows its publisher and IIRC is allowed to automatically redirect local drives & printers, while "normal" unsigned .rdp files show warning messages before doing so.

As a workaround, you could strip the signature, i.e. revert the file to unsigned. Open the .rdp file in Notepad, then delete the extremely long line starting with `signature:s:`. (Notepad might show it as multiple lines; just delete it all.)